# Convert from Int to Date in PyMongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection where one of the fields has a key "updatedAt". It's supposed to store the date when the document was updated. It's currently stored as an integer, an example value is 1620430691. I'm assuming it's a "long integer": https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/ which

> Returns a date that corresponds to the number of milliseconds represented by the long value.

> Positive number corresponds to the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

> Negative number corresponds to the number of milliseconds before Jan 1, 1970.

In any case, I'm trying use PyMongo aggregation framework to convert from integer to date.

What I've tried is:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$project': {
            'updatedAt': {
                '$cond': {
                    'if': {'$ne': ["$updatedAt", ""]},
                    'then': {'$toDate': "$updatedAt"},
                    'else': ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

results = list(client.db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
```

but then I get the following error

```
OperationFailure: Unsupported conversion from int to date in $convert with no onError value, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1668566538, 2), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Unsupported conversion from int to date in $convert with no onError value', 'code': 241, 'codeName': 'ConversionFailure', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1668566538, 2), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xc1\x11\x98Z\xf4\xec\xb4\x87v\xcfA\x97\xf0ph\n\xd1\x84\xa2>', 'keyId': 7119177789432922116}}}
```

Comment: The error message is coming from the MongoDB server so `"updatedAt"` is probably stored as a BSON int.  `"$toDate"` needs a BSON long if it's an integer.

Comment: What's the best way to convert to BSON long in PyMongo first?

Comment: Have a look at https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/int64.html

Comment: This answer may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987750